# Which class implements iterator's Next() method?

Tags: java, iterator

my question may be newbish or even repetitive, but still i haven't found the answer yet. 
iterator() method returns an iterator, which has several methods, say, next(). But where are these methods implemented? Interfaces cannot implement methods, right?

For example:

```
Set keys = selector.selectedKeys();
Iterator it = keys.iterator();
While (it.hasNext())
```

Also, `it` is not a reference to an object, right? What is it then?

Comment: check this http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html

Comment: little trick: object.iterator().getClass().getName() shows you the actual class of the object that is returned as the implementation. If you really must know the implementation class to investigate a problem, its easy to find out this way (even easier than using a debugger if you ask me).

Comment: @Gimby right, somehow didn't try to do that, thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are correct, interfaces can't implement methods.

The beauty of programming towards interfaces is that you don't need to worry about where they are implemented. All you need to know is that `Set#iterator()` returns a class that implements the `Iterator` interface. This way, if the returned class containing the implementation should change, this won't matter to your code.

Answer (score 1):

`iterator()` will actually return an *implementation* of `Iterator`, i.e. an instance of a class that implements `Iterator`. Usually this class is different depending on what collection you call `iterator()`.

This is the main advantage of interfaces: They just define some contract that implementations must follow (in this case it defines several methods and how they should behave like), but don't actually provide an implementation of that contract, so that the implementation can be defined at the appropriate location.

Answer (score 1):

If you use an IDE such as Eclipse, you can query the list of classes that implement `Iterator`. Just select the word `Iterator` in your code and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>t</kbd>. Other IDEs will have their own way of doing this.

You'll see countless different iterators that are included in Oracle non-public code (and from other libraries you use). It is an instance of one of these classes that are returned when you request an iterator from a set.

To find out which particular iterator is used with a certain object type, browse the source and see for yourself! Or [print the name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21425783/which-class-implements-iterators-next-method/21425904#comment32324436_21425783) by calling `.getClass().getName()` on the iterator instance.

For instance, a `HashSet` uses a private iterator class `HashMap.KeyIterator`, which extends a parent class `HashMap.HashIterator`.

[image: iterator screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

In your case the Set keys object is a concrete implementation like

> All Known Implementing Classes:
>   AbstractSet, ConcurrentSkipListSet, CopyOnWriteArraySet, EnumSet, HashSet, JobStateReasons, LinkedHashSet, TreeSet

and they implement Iterable.

for example the [TreeSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html) imeplements Iterable

> All Implemented Interfaces:
>   Serializable, Cloneable, Iterable, Collection, NavigableSet, Set, SortedSet

Answer (score 0):

Interfaces can't implement methods, that's right.

But `it` *is* a reference to an object, specifically one that implements the `Iterator` interface.

If the interface says a method returns an iterator, it is the responsibility of whoever creates an implementation of that interface to also provide an implementation of Iterator that can be returned by those methods. They may be able to reuse an existing iterator over their internal data structures, or they may need to create a new one.

Answer (score 0):

Think of an Interface as a "contract".

When you write a program and you say "it is an Iterator", what the compiler (or interpreter, whatever) "understands" is that anything that declares a method expected by that Interface will be accepted. This provides flexibility to your program and this what object oriented languages are all about.

Now, when the program needs to be effectively executed, the interpreter will start to search all the internal dependencies to find out what piece of code will actually execute that "contract". That's resolved dynamically by JAVA.

In this case, JAVA will see that "it" is the iterator of "keys". Then it will also see that "keys" is another interface (Set) that is actually referring to a concrete Set implementation (some piece of code that can be actually executed) which is selector.selectedKeys().

But if "selector" is another interface, then JAVA will continue searching until it finds someone that can actually execute the code, and the thing goes on. :-)

Answer (score 0):

In those implementation of collection class, there is an inner class which implements the Iterator interface. It is the inner class that implements all the methods for Iterator interface. Like ArrayList, inside its implementation, there is

```
private class Itr implements Iterator<E> {
        int cursor;       // index of next element to return
        int lastRet = -1; // index of last element returned; -1 if no such
        int expectedModCount = modCount;

        public boolean hasNext() {
            return cursor != size;
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        public E next() {
            checkForComodification();
            int i = cursor;
            if (i >= size)
                throw new NoSuchElementException();
            Object[] elementData = ArrayList.this.elementData;
            if (i >= elementData.length)
                throw new ConcurrentModificationException();
            cursor = i + 1;
            return (E) elementData[lastRet = i];
        }

        ...
}
```

It is better for you to learn it from the jdk source code. I hope this answer can help you.

Answer (score 0):

You should approach it this way.

```
Set keys = selector.selectedKeys();
```

The above statement should be read like this," I have a reference keys which points some implementation of Set interface. The implementation which it points to can be found in the return type of selectedkeys(). The implementation could be a hashSet, linkedHashSet or any other class which implements Set. Also if you check the set interface it extends collections which inturn extends iterable. So from the interface it becomes obvious that any implementation of Set will surely implement iterator()

```
Iterator it = keys.iterator();
```

This line should be read as "call the iterator method of the implementing class to which the reference keys points to" So to get the implementation of Iterator you need to first identify the Implementation which keys points to. The source code has all the answers to these questions. Try and dig deeper into the collections source code and you would find the various Set implementations and you can see how Iterator is implemented.

Answer (score -1):

in short: `Set<E>` `extends` a superinterface `Iterable<E>` and so passes down the methods from `Iterable<E>`

The object `keys` will thus have access to these methods.

[Here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html)'s the link to the docs.